# Compact submanifold of the projective space and semismple algebraic group action

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $X$ be a compact submanifold of $\mathbb CP^n$ such that there exists a semisimple complex linear algebraic group $G$ acts transitively on $X$. If $X$ is $G$-equivariantly embedded in $\mathbb CP^n$. How to show that $X$ is a flag manifold?